# Downloaded picture from pixabay using it's api but downloaded image is not supported in windows photo viewer

Tags: python

i have downloaded a picture from pixabay using it's API and saved it locally as a .jpg file .But the problem is windows photo viewer is telling me it doesn't support this format. here's the code,

```
import urllib.request
import python_pixabay

pix = python_pixabay.Pixabay('4119664-75cc2144f4a944b21e461e646')

# default image search
img_search = pix.image_search()

cis = pix.image_search()

#url to the original image
u = cis['hits'][1]['pageURL']

urllib.request.urlretrieve(u, "local-filename.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not downloading the image itself. With `urllib.request.urlretrieve(u, "local-filename.jpg")` you are saving the HTML of URL `u` to `local-filename.jpg`. If you inspect you can see that your URL `u` looks like `https://pixabay.com/en/flowers-spring-season-nature-3231089/`. You need to parse the HTML of that URL, find the image link and download the image. You can use packages like `Beautiful Soup` to do that.

Comment: thanks a lot .I thought as its saving the file as .jpg it must be an image. And also it turns out i could use the key 'largeImageURL' instead of 'pageURL' to download the picture.though it's not the best quality image.